# Loading LD_PRELOAD symbols with CDLL(None) in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use `ctypes.CDLL(None)` to get access to the symbols of the current executable, which works well for Python 2.7.5 and 3.11.2 but not with python 3.6.8. I can't figure why there is a difference in behavior. Example:

The shared object:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
  printf("foo called\n");
}
```

Compiled with `gcc -fPIC -shared foo.c libfoo.so`.

The Python program:

```py
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL(None)
foo = lib["foo"]
foo()
```

Then I run the test program:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libfoo.so python2 test.py
foo called
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libfoo.so python3.11 test.py
foo called
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libfoo.so python3.6 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    foo = lib["foo"]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 361, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: python3: undefined symbol: foo
```

How can I have the behavior of Python 2.7 and 3.11 with 3.6?